# Change the value of the key, then delete the key on comma delimited CSV using regex

Tags: regex, excel, csv, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I got this pattern:

`...,432,3333333,607,5500,617,5000,...
...,66,88,432,22625,607,45330,617,5000,...
...,432,3600000,607,87,617,5000,...`

From a multi columned csv file delimited by comma,
The data should be, the first column should be the key, the second column should be the value, so what I was asked to do is to set all specific keys to zero, and delete the key

I need to delete all "607" keys to the csv hence, the above should result to:

`...,432,3333333,0,0,617,5000,...
...,66,88,432,22625,0,0,617,5000,...
...,432,3600000,0,0,617,5000,...`

Hope this can be done in regex, because this can't be done anymore in excel.

Thanks!

Comment: Your data don't show the key as the first column? If there are any other values of 607 in other columns of your data set, you will zap them unless you specify a particular column.

Comment: I mean, the number of columns is even, so: `...key,value,key,value,key,value,...`

Comment: I see. I don't think regex is a good tool for this. A simple script would be safer.

Comment: i favor regex since it is a .txt format csv file which I only need a notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
,607,[^,]*
```

Replacement string:

```
,0,0
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kZ9zW6/6)

Comment: Thanks man! works even on "...,1607,3600000,607,87,617,5000,..."

Comment: Are there any other values of `607,` in other columns?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :)

```
var s = '...,432,3333333,607,5500,617,5000,...';
var p = /,607,\d+/g
console.log(s.replace(p, ',0,0'));
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sahefemu/1/edit?html,js,output)