# start search and replace after the nth comma using regex using notepad++

Tags: regex, csv, delimiter

I have a comma delimited txt file, Is there a way regex can do search and replace ONLY after the nth comma, say, after 3rd comma
so:

`data1,data2,data3,regex,can,start,search,and,replace,here`

Actually I need to perform this regex expresion

Find: `,key1,[^,]*`

Replace: `,0,0`

which I learned from [Change the value of the key, then delete the key on comma delimited CSV using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020757/change-the-value-of-the-key-then-delete-the-key-on-comma-delimited-csv-using-re)

Hope I can do the same operation ONLY after the nth comma

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what flavor of regex you're using, so you may have to fix it up a little (possibly escape parens/brackets), but your regex should look something like this:

```
^([^,]*,){n,}key1,[^,]*
```

Where `[^,]*,` matches a field in the CSV and the comma after it, and `([^,]*,){n}` (replace `n` with a number) matches that n times. For example, with sed you could use

```
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{2\}\)key1,[^,]*,/\10,0,/' foo.csv
```

to replace `key1,whatever` with `0,0` after the second comma.

If you mean after the nth or a later comma, use `{n,}` instead of `{n}` (that means "match n or more times).

Comment: how about with notepad++ bro? not really familiar with "sed"

Comment: I'm not familiar with notepad++, but if I read their documentation correctly, the first regex should simply work. Have you tried it?